# In Android Studio What do I Use For HTTP Call "org.apache.http." or "Volley"

Tags: java, android, apache, android-volley

At This time I am using "*org.apache.http*" But I heard Support for "*org.apache.http*" is remove from android SDK.
To use "*org.apache.http*" in my app I am Writing a line in "*build.gradle*" **"useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'"** is it OK to use like this or Shift to "Volley"

Comment: You can use HttpURLConnection. It is easy to implement than using any library.http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

It's a proper alternative to org.apache.http and well integrated in Android.

Also if you plain to use your HTTP calls for API implementation, [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) encapsulate it with some awesome Rest API helper.